# How to setup a JDBC NamedParameter to be surrounded by double quotes?

Tags: jdbc, prepared-statement, jdbctemplate, named-parameters

Im using postgres@9.6 and I'm trying to do a query with a collate. The collate seems to require double quotes around the locale, for ex:

```
SELECT ... ORDER BY c.id COLLATE "en-US" ...
```

but of course I want the collation to be passed as an argument, so when I try and build the sql query string with escaping the quotes like this:

```
"SELECT ... ORDER BY c.id COLLATE \":locale\", ..."
```

but deeper in the JDBC code (specifically ***NamedParameterUtils.skipCommentsAndQuotes(...)***), it ignores anything in quotes as a string constant, and doesn't replace the parameter.

I also tried single quotes, double double quotes, no quotes... nothing working....

Any ideas?

Comment: The collation clause is not parametrizable: it is an object name, not a value. You can only use parameters for values (in expressions or column assignments).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Unfortunate. So the only solution is to generate a new sql string each time?

Comment: I think so, yes.